# sort items in a text file seperated by commas

Tags: bash, csv, sorting

I have a single line text file with strings in quotes and separated by commas like this

unsorted.txt

> "JANE","BOB","TIM","HARRY"

how can I sort alphabetically the items using bash, I would like to save to
sorted.txt

> "BOB","HARRY","JANE","TIM"

I have tried this and it only sorts lines, but there is only one line.

> sort -t, unsorted.txt > sorted.txt

How would I go about this?

Comment: only one line? or you want to sort columns according to the headers?

Comment: this will be nontrivial to handle if the csv contains data and OP requires to sort all the columns according to the headers.

Comment: ok maybe it is not a true csv file since it has no header, it is just one line of text separated by commas with quotes around each string.

Answer (score 2):

With Perl:

```
perl -F, -lane 'print join ",", sort @F' unsorted.txt
```

Output:

```
"BOB","HARRY","JANE","TIM"
```

Comment: how come you're using printf?

Comment: @123: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Without perl:

```
echo '"JANE","BOB","TIM","HARRY"' | tr -s ',' '\n' | sort | tr -s '\n' ',' | sed s/,$//g
```

First, convert commas to newlines, pipe to sort, convert back to comma, and remove the comma on the last line with sed.

Answer (score 0):

with `awk`

```
awk -F, '{split($0,a); asort(a); for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s", a[i] (i==n?ORS:FS)}'
```

Answer (score 0):

another one with bash + sort

```
echo '"JANE","BOB","TIM","HARRY"'|while IFS=',' read -a l;do g=$(printf "%s\n" ${l[*]}|sort);echo ${g//$'\n'/","}; done
```